# Web based MP3 Player .net c# set URL in code not in HTML

Tags: c#, .net, mp3

I am looking for a Web based mp3 player that will work in .net. The website is written in c#. It needs to play, stop and pause MP3's. It should play mp3s from a folder inside the web project and I need to set the location of the mp3's in code so the user cannot find the mp3 location from the html.

It also need to log that the user has played the mp3 so I need access to an event to do this

I have tried `WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer` but cannot get the pause and resume working.

here is the code but the mpthree instance keeps getting reset

WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer mpthree;

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mpthree == null)
        {
            mpthree = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        }
    }

    protected void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mpthree.URL = Server.MapPath("/MP3s/20130101003811_442071839757_anonymous-all.mp3");
        mpthree.controls.currentPosition = Convert.ToDouble(Session["currentPos"]);

        mpthree.controls.play();      
    }

    protected void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mpthree.controls.stop();
        Session["currentPos"] = 0;
    }

    protected void Pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mpthree.controls.pause();
        Session["currentPos"] = mpthree.controls.currentPosition;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you aren't understanding the concept of HTTP. It doesn't matter if you set the MP3 source server or client side, the client will always know where the file is coming from since, well, the browser must download it in order to play. The resulting HTML you send to the client will always contain the URL from where the file will be downloaded

Comment: the play, stop, pause should definitely **not** be handled by c# code. That's an extreme waste of http requests. Those things should be handled by javascript/jquery. Users will not enjoy the post back required.